# I had problems with Blazor Wasm with login, it adds /authentication to the path of CSS and js

Tags: authentication, blazor, webassembly

First, excuse my grammar I am not an English speaker.

I'm having problems with my blazor server core hosted app. When I press login button it gives errors  due to "/authentication" being added to the paths of the CSS and js files. For example, the route should be: `https://localhost:7293/js/buttons.js`, but it looks for it at `https://localhost:7293/authentication/js/buttons.js` and these errors appear constantly.

The most serious one is that `blazor.webassembly.js` can't find `/_framework/blazor.boot.json`, which leads to various errors.

I have looked for "/authentication" in the whole solution but I couldn't find it. I will share my startup in order to see if the error is there:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");


builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    );


builder.Services.AddDbContext<ProtegiaContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(
                    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                    sqlServerOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                    {
                        sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure();  
                    }), ServiceLifetime.Transient);

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength =8;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;

})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    //.AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
        options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
        options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
    });
// Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler
    .DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role"); 


builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
                x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Program));

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(); `

builder.Services.AddControllers(options => options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true);
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    //app.UseBrowserLink();
}


app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

Comment: What does the header in your index.html  look like?

Comment: Hi, maybe you are requesting me this: 
<head>
    <base />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="img/Logos/protegia.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/Logos/protegia.ico">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <title>
        PROTEGIA
    </title>

    <!--     Fonts and icons     and other css styles-->
  
</head>